# JqueryTools expose close on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I disabled the default .expose() closeonclick function because i want to close it with button. The problem is i cant find the code how to properly close it.

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){

...?

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call on button click:

```
$.mask.close();
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmpRy/)